# How on MacOS from bash script (or installer) inform system restart is requried (which can be postoned by a user)

Tags: macos, bash, installer, macos-ventura, macos-sonoma

I have some post installation script which on some version of MacOS system does some system tweaks. This changes will take effect when system is restarted.

I do not want to restart machine immediately. I'm looking for a way that user is promoted or notification is shown by system, that it is recommended to restart system. User should be able to postpone restart as he wishes.

I need to do it in two ways:

- from instillation package in post install script (or by JavaScript action installer provides) - this should happen when my software is installed on Sonoma
- from user bash script which could be run by user in case he install my software on Ventura and then he upgraded system to Sonoma.

Comment: How are you making your installer? A graphical installer? Command-line?